# how to pass account information to django template in django-registration?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-registration, django-class-based-views

I want to pass the `account information` to the `template` so that when an `user account` is activated, there is a message saying "your account is activated; please log in now" with a link below. if the `activation days` have expired, it must say "activation days expired".  I have url and template here, but I do not know how to pass the account information to the template.

`url.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^activate/complete/$',
                           TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/activate.html'),
                           name='registration_activation_complete'),
......)
```

`registration/activate.html`

```
{% extends "registration/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Account activated{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Account activated.</h1>
  {% load humanize %}
  {% if account %}
    <p>Thanks for signing up! Now you can <a href="/accounts/login/">log in</a>.</p>
  {% else %}
    <p>Sorry, it didn't work. Either your activation link was incorrect, or
    the activation key for your account has expired; activation keys are
    only valid for {{ expiration_days|apnumber }} days after
    registration.</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

basically, I want to pass `account` and `expiration_days` to the above template. I just don't know how. help plz!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it won't be enough just to use `TemplateView` like you did; you'll have to write a custom view which will contain the logic for activation and pass the data to the template.