# how does get_sucess_url work in django?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I am going through the `source code` of `django-registration`. Here is a class-based view that is defined. I am having hard time understanding how the `get_success_url` work? 
From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/),

```
 get_success_url()
    Determine the URL to redirect to when the form is successfully validated. 
Returnsdjango.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.success_url if it is provided; 
otherwise, attempts to use the get_absolute_url() of the object.
```

but how does this work in the example code below: 
why are the `two arguments empty`? what are they supposed to take?

```
class ActivationView(BaseActivationView):
    def activate(self, request, activation_key):
        """
        Given an an activation key, look up and activate the user
        account corresponding to that key (if possible).

        After successful activation, the signal
        ``registration.signals.user_activated`` will be sent, with the
        newly activated ``User`` as the keyword argument ``user`` and
        the class of this backend as the sender.

        """
        activated_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.activate_user(activation_key)
        if activated_user:
            signals.user_activated.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                        user=activated_user,
                                        request=request)
        return activated_user

    def get_success_url(self, request, user):
        return ('registration_activation_complete', (), {})
```

Answer (score 2):

These three arguments are passed to Django's [reverse URL lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls), specifically the `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` function. The `()` (empty tuple) gives the positional arguments, the `{}` (empty dictionary) gives the keyword arguments. So what ends up being passed is:

```
reverse('registration_activation_complete', args=(), kwargs={})
```

You can see in the [urls.py](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/backends/default/urls.py?at=default) file that the `registration_activation_complete` URL takes no arguments (the URL is just `activate/complete/$`), which is why those are empty.

Comment: if I am correct, `get_success_url` is called only when the form is successfully validated. so what is called when it is not validated? is there a `get_failure_url`?

Comment: @eagertoLearn: If the form is not successfully validated it does what invalid forms do in Django by default (go back to the form page with some error messages added to the form). If you wanted to customize that, you could implement a `form_invalid` method (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/)). That method could return an HttpResponseRedirect to a new URL if you want (though it's unclear why you would- when someone fails to register you usually wouldn't send them to a *new* page)

Comment: Thanks! I have been trying to pass a different `url` to `get_success_url`, that would take arguments, which I have posted in a different manner here. Looks like it is not trivial (atleast to me). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622738/how-to-pass-account-information-to-django-template-in-django-registration

Comment: @eagertoLearn: you *can* pass a different `url`, but it looks like what you're trying is to have a failure message on that `get_success_url` page. Why not just handle this by form validation? That is, if the registration fails, raise a ValidationError?

Comment: I want to pass a different url that needs parameters (such as `account`) for the template. This is not a form validation actually (because a user activates his account by clicking the link sent to email, if for some reason, the link has expired, then I want to display different message. A single template depending on if the account is activated should handle both (if you look at other post, you might see, I do a `if` check in template for `account being active`

Comment: @eagertoLearn: Ah, I understand. Then can you share the code where you are creating the account and/or checking whether it *can* be created?

Comment: here is the code, I am working on https://github.com/sridhar1982/djangoRegistration. you can ingnore the customRegistration App

Comment: I want to direct to `template activate.html` once the registration is complete (which means registered and activated by clicking the link). but currently I am going to `activation_complete.html`